# Good GIS Software or Components for Windows PC in .NET?

Tags: c#, components, gis, geography

Last week i searched for good free or opensource solutions and component for GIS (Geographical  Information Systems) I founded some system but no one fill my requirements

- SharpMap is very buggy software
- Gmap.net is very slow
- MapWindow have a very complex structure and is very buggy.

I founded uDIG but is in java, i need a solution in vb.net or c#.

Anyone know a good solution that fill my requirements or have alternatives, i accept solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are limiting yourself a lot by insisting on .NET. I don't know of anything other than SharpMap or [MapWinGIS ActiveX](http://www.mapwindow.com) (MapWindow). Here are some free, but not .NET, options for Windows desktop applications.

If you'd consider writing your standalone application in Python or C++:

- [Mapnik](http://www.mapnik.org/faq/)
- [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/)

Or if you'd consider writing a plug-in or a customisation for an existing GIS:

- [GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/) can be customised in [Python](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python), Perl, Ruby...
- [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) can be customised in [Python](http://desktopgisbook.com/node/19)

Answer (score 3):

I think that you've covered it already. There really aren't any production quality open source GIS project out there using C#. Most of the good work is being done in Java, C/C++ or Python these days. If you must use the .NET Framework then I think the best of the bunch is indeed SharpMap.

Failing that you need to look at commercial products from companies like http://www.esri.com. Of course, it also depends on what you need: web services, Windows Forms control, WPF, etc. In the past I've managed to whip up some C# that constructed the right XML to send to a Java server-based mapping engine, so you could look at something like GeoServer and build your own client. Obviously not what you want to get in to but I don't see that you have many options beyond the ones you've listed.

Comment: I follow ESRI and worked with software from this guys. But actually my company don't have funds to buy and license ESRI software. I see ESRI created the ARCGIS Explorer is cool product and is extensible. Cool i can use it its very professional.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to look in to [MapAround](http://www.maparound.ru)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out SharpMap? It's available on [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpMap).

Comment: I wrote wrong i edited my text from SharpGis to SharpMap.

Answer (score 0):

[MapSurfer.NET](http://mapsurfernet.com) framework might be a good option.

MapSurfer.NET is free, modern cartographic framework which is able to provide maps of superior cartographic quality. This framework supports a bunch [spatial data formats](http://mapsurfernet.com/docs/usermanual/data_sources/vector/index) (e.g., Shape files, PostgreSQL, OSM, etc.) and web services (e.g., CartoDB, Mapzen, etc.). Furthermore, its setup includes MapSurfer.NET Studio application which allows creating and editing map styles (analogue of TileMill). Its symbology is inspired by both OGC specifications and other similar toolkits such as MapServer, GeoServer or Mapnik.

Answer (score -1):

We use Mapzania (http://www.mapzania.com).

The best thing about it is that you load it into existing web-applications via a NuGet package and then you get a bunch of GIS functionality.

It uses Leaflet as its front-end and it has JS library that makes it easy to do stuff to Leaflet.

It also has a nice MapStyler for creating and editing maps.

Comment: Please give reason for down-vote.