# What control to use for maps

Tags: c#, mapping, gis

I am developing Earthquake Risk Analysis Software. In this application, I have to use some maps to show the layout of places that are most vulnerable to seismic activities based on some calculations.

For maps that show danger zones MapWinGis is known to me but I was thinking that can I use some other library or control that is more powerful and yet provides some excellent features.

Can I use google maps? What are other viable alternatives?

[image: Image Generated by MapWinGis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free and open source

- [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) JavaScript control with [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org/) or [MapServer](https://mapserver.org/) on the server, and [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) for free map images
- [SharpMap](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110213533/http://sharpmap.codeplex.com:80/) has .Net controls for web and desktop
- You can write plugins for the free GIS packages like [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org) and [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/)

Commercial

- ESRI ArcGIS is very popular. [ArcEngine](https://developers.arcgis.com/) can be used for desktop applications, [ArcGIS Server](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-enterprise/overview?rsource=/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/index.html) has JavaScript, Silverlight and Flex APIs, [ArcGIS Explorer](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-field-maps/overview?rsource=https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-explorer/overview&rsource=/software/arcgis/explorer) is a free desktop GIS reader that you can [customise](https://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/index.html).

See also the question [Good GIS Software or Components for Windows PC in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162007/good-gis-software-or-components-for-windows-pc-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two links might help if you are looking for a map components.

- This is a list that contains many components for mapping.
  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services
- This is a compare table for the mapping software and components.
  http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Comparison_of_GIS_software

Our company researched several components, you could pay attention to those companies:

- [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com) provides many native opensource map components.
- [ThinkGeo](http://www.thinkgeo.com) covers almost all platforms under .NET framework.
- [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/maps) provides community license for small business for mapping.
- [SlimGIS](https://www.slimgis.com) provides cross-platform map components for .NET, ASP.NET Core and Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what technologies you want to use. This looks good though:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/google_earth_embed.aspx

Comment: can i mention areas which are at risk like change color or somthing

Answer (score 0):

Bing maps has an excellent API - though I am not sure how powerful it would be for your applications. It plays very nicely with ASP.NET

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx