# Commercial or Open Source Mapping Control for Winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, dictionary, offline

Our company is building a Winforms application that needs a map control to help keep track of property surveys.

We are currently using GMaps.NET - http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

The problem is we need offline map tiles for the entire of Australia at pretty high zoom levels (about lvl 18 using google maps) and the only way to achieve this using GMaps is to prefetch data from an online service.

Does anyone know of a Commercial or Open Source Winforms map control that:

- Can provide, or use offline map data
- Can draw polygons or markers
- Lets you select a point on the map and gives you the Latitude / Longitude

Comment: what is the problem with prefetching the data?

Comment: The problem with prefetching the data is that it would take forever to prefetch all of Australia down to that kind of zoom level and only legal for the open source maps, like openstreetmap.org

Comment: Here is a relative question "[What control to use for maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462746/what-control-to-use-for-maps/45294145#45294145)" that you could find more options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Source [SharpMap](https://github.com/SharpMap) has all the features you are requesting. It supports at least JPG raster layers. In commercial products, [TatukGIS](http://www.tatukgis.com/) is a fairly inexpensive GIS SDK for .NET. If you want to spend the money, [ESRI ArcObjects SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/ao_home.html) supports all kinds of offline raster layers.

Comment: Cheers, I'm also taking a looks at these suggestions, I'll tick the answer of the best one :)

Comment: SharpMap seems to be the best fit here. The problem I'm still having is getting an offline database/file containing map tiles for most of australia. It seems that most people have cadastral data, but no background map to place it over. The goal is essentially an offline google maps with the ability to place a cadastral layer over the top.

Answer (score 2):

We use [MapWinGIS ActiveX Control](http://www.mapwindow.org/downloads/index.php?show_details=2). It uses Shapefile format maps, which can be found all over and can be zoomed in to minute detail as they contain vector data. You can draw your own shapes using the control (You have to write the code of course, but it is not massively difficult and we have achieved it in our software) and as long as you get a shapefile that has a georeferenced position, you will be able to get the Lat/Long of a point and even measure distances (We do both in our software).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers, I'm taking a look at your suggestion now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [EsayGIS](http://www.easygisdotnet.com/%E2%80%8E) in my project. It's easy to use and supports shape files and online map services. I'm not sure about offline map data but I think it's supported.